Excel formula tiering values in data set based on country values are in
I need to be able to use a table and look at one column of values and tier these in the following way:
Top 20% is Tier 1, Tier 2 next 30%, Tier 3 bottom 50%,  tier 4 no performance data.
EG if there are 25 values for a country, then the top 20% values will be the top 5 values (25*0.2)
This needs to be done for each country individually, AND the values and number of values for each country differ (see table below).



Country
Rate




Argentina
0.04


Argentina
0.11


Argentina
0.00


Argentina
0.14


Argentina
0.00


Argentina
0.04


Argentina
0.09


Argentina
0.13


Argentina
0.40


Argentina
0.00


Argentina



Argentina



Australia
0.66


Australia
0.30


Australia
0.37


Australia
0.38


Australia
0.37


Australia
0.33


Australia
0.32


Australia
0.12


Australia
0.19


Australia
0.10


Australia
0.11


Australia
0.00


Australia
0.00


Australia
0.00


Austria
1.47


Austria
1.05


Austria
0.50


Austria
0.14


Belgium
0.07


Belgium
0.37


Belgium
0.11


Belgium
0.05


Belgium



Belgium



Brazil
0.39


Brazil
0.31


Brazil
0.74


Brazil
0.35


Brazil
0.15


Brazil
0.60


Brazil
0.24


Brazil
0.22


Brazil
0.23


Brazil
0.22


Brazil
0.29


Brazil
0.14


Brazil
0.24


Brazil
0.05


Brazil
0.10


Brazil



Brazil




E.G:
I have done this manually for Canada:



Country
Rate
Tier




Canada
0.27
2


Canada
0.13
3


Canada
0.06
3


Canada
0.00
3


Canada
0.00
3


Canada
0.00
3


Canada
0.00
3


Canada
1.33
1


Canada
0.76
1


Canada
0.33
1


Canada
0.32
1


Canada
0.28
1


Canada
0.19
2


Canada
0.24
2


Canada
0.23
2


Canada
0.19
2


Canada
0.16
2


Canada
0.16
2


Canada
0.15
3


Canada
0.15
3


Canada
0.13
3


Canada
0.10
3


Canada
0.08
3


Canada
0.15
3


Canada
0.05
3



Any and all help would be massive appreciated :)

Can you explain how you get your top 20%. For Canada =0.32-0.32*20% equals 0.256, but that's not the logic used. Do you mean PERCENTOF? Please explain yourself.

(instead of posting the logic in a comment it may benefit your question's quality to edit it in there)

I have posted the incorrect table above, it has now been edited thank you

but what is the logic used; why is 0.27 for Canada calculated in tier 2 and 0.28 in tier 1 for instance?

because Tier 1 is the 5 highest rates, 0.27 is the 6th value in the list so falls into tier 2

Yes, you got multiple answers to choose from in the meantime. As you can see, changing the data to table (ctrl+t) is advisable.

Another solution using a table:
=LET(countryData,FILTER([Rate],([Country]=[@Country])*([Rate]<>"")),
    rankedValue,IFNA(PERCENTRANK.INC(countryData,[@Rate]),0),
    XLOOKUP(rankedValue,{0.8;0.5;0},{1;2;3},"",-1))



Cool, never saw PERCENTRANK.INC before. Nice usecase for it indeed.

I believe your hand calculated tiers are incorrect. However, here is a starter method which you will need to tweak to get working per your own logic.
First insert a helper column that gets the "border" point for the top 20% - formula is
=IFERROR(PERCENTILE.INC(IF($A$2:$A$80=A2, $B$2:$B$80), 0.2), "")

Do the same for the 50% point
=IFERROR(PERCENTILE.INC(IF($A$2:$A$80=A2, $B$2:$B$80), 0.5), "")

The column for calculating the tier then becomes
=IF(B2="", 4, IF(B2>=C2, 1, IF(B2>=D2, 2, 3)))

I've assumed Country is in column A, Rate in Column B. Watch out for the row range - I've only used 2 to 80

Thank you for these recommendations, but I have used the solution from IKE which was the fastest for what I needed :)

Not sure if I understood the logic correctly:
=IF([@Rate]="",4,XMATCH(PERCENTOF(XMATCH([@Rate],SORT(FILTER([Rate],[Country]=[@Country]))),ROWS(FILTER([Rate],[Country]=[@Country]))),{1;0.8;0.5},1))
This checks if a value is within the 20% of rows of values that are highest, next 30%, etc.
Not sure how you expect it to behave in case there would be an overlap of values in tiers.
Using PERCENTRANK.INC (which I didn't know existed before reading the answers):
=IF([@Rate]="",4,XMATCH(PERCENTRANK.INC(FILTER([Rate],[Country]=[@Country]),[@Rate]),{1,0.8,0.5},1))
or:
=IF([@Rate]="",4,3-SUM(N(PERCENTRANK.INC(FILTER([Rate],[Country]=[@Country]),[@Rate])>{1,0.8,0.5})))
or using ranges:
=LET(d,A2:C26,a,TAKE(d,,1),b,INDEX(d,,2),MAP(a,b,LAMBDA(c,d,IF(d="",4,XMATCH(PERCENTRANK.INC(FILTER(b,a=c),d),{1,0.8,0.5},1)))))

Based on Ike's very nice answer, using REDUCE to have result outside the table; not sure whether it will improve performance.
=LET(
    percentages_for_tiers, {0.8, 0.5, 0},
    tiers, SEQUENCE(, COUNT(percentages_for_tiers)),
    has_value, LAMBDA(a, LEN(TRIM(a))),
    rate_tier, LAMBDA(country,
        LET(
            rates_for_country, FILTER(
                RatesByCounty[Rate],
                RatesByCounty[Country] = country
            ),
            non_empty_rates, FILTER(
                RatesByCounty[Rate],
                has_value(RatesByCounty[Rate]) *
                    (RatesByCounty[Country] = country)
            ),
            ranked_values, PERCENTRANK.INC(
                non_empty_rates,
                rates_for_country
            ),
            tier, XLOOKUP(
                ranked_values,
                percentages_for_tiers,
                tiers,
                ,
                -1
            ),
            comment_1, "Filter etc. return 0 for blank cells, so replace these zeros",
            non_empty_rate, FILTER(
                has_value(RatesByCounty[Rate]),
                RatesByCounty[Country] = country
            ),
            IF(non_empty_rate, tier, "")
        )
    ),
    result, REDUCE(
        "Tier",
        UNIQUE(RatesByCounty[Country]),
        LAMBDA(acc, cur, VSTACK(acc, rate_tier(cur)))
    ),
    result
)



I don't think reduce/vstack is advisable/required in this case. MAP or BYROW could simulate the table (see last option in my answer). Nevertheless, nicely designed.

Thank you P.b - I'll look into it after my morning coffee ;)

@P.b, since percentile rank is based primarily on county, I'm getting it (and thus the tier) only once per country, rather than filtering and calculating for each row. I'm using reduce to handle nested arrays for countries. With my limited Excel experience, I couldn't find a way to improve this - when you have time, could you please MAP it out? Thanks again.

You might be right with that. I'll test it later.
